# How can I rewrite this postgresql query without subquery? How can I increase performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

```
select x1
from my_project.my_table as x1
where x1.value = :value
  and x1.name <> :name
  and x1.data1 in (select distinct x2.data1 - 1
                   from my_project.my_table as x2
                   where x2.name=:name)
order by x1.id asc;
```

Comment: Show us table and index definitions. and the explain output.

Comment: And please, use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this statement, not just EXPLAIN

Comment: Could you also tell us what this query is doing? Some sample data and your expected results would help.

Answer (score 0):

A strange query. A trivial improvement is to get rid of the useless `DISTINCT` that will only harm performance.

If the table is large, but the rows selected by the `WHERE` condition are few, the following may perform better, if properly indexed:

```
select x1
from my_project.my_table as x1
where x1.value = :value
  and x1.name <> :name
  and EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_project.my_table as x2
              WHERE x1.data = x2.data - 1
                AND x2.name = :name)
order by x1.id asc;
```